# Removing letters from string in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a string SOFTMAAWCKOVENRFLLOW from which I would like to remove the first occurrence of each character in a second string WOLFMAN, which would result in the string STACKOVERFLOW.

[Example Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18XGwRkJjRUfNrGcNUoj8kb1lix5zp1tQ-p43mCV89MQ/edit?usp=sharing)

I'm seeking a way to do this in Google Sheets with a single formula, without relying on GAS to create a custom function.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Exact copy of [Removing first occurrence of letters from string](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/162969761) that has an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this to get started:

```
=substitute( substitute( substitute( substitute( substitute( substitute( substitute( 
  A2, 
  "W", "", 1 ), 
  "O", "", 1 ), 
  "L", "", 1 ), 
  "F", "", 1 ), 
  "M", "", 1 ), 
  "A", "", 1 ), 
  "N", "", 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=JOIN(, FILTER(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2&"", "(.)", "$1×"), "×")), 
 NOT(COUNTIF(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(B2&"", "(.)", "$1♦×"), "×"))&
 COUNTIFS(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(B2&"", "(.)", "$1×"), "×")), 
 FLATTEN(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(B2&"", "(.)", "$1×"), "×")), 
 SEQUENCE(LEN(B2)), "<="&SEQUENCE(LEN(B2))), 
 FLATTEN(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2&"", "(.)", "$1♦×"), "×"))&
 COUNTIFS(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2&"", "(.)", "$1×"), "×")), 
 FLATTEN(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2&"", "(.)", "$1×"), "×")), 
 SEQUENCE(LEN(A2)), "<="&SEQUENCE(LEN(A2)))))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem with a **single formula** by trying to combine two useful functions `SUBSTITUTE` and `MID`.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2;MID(B2;10;1);"";1);MID(B2;9;1);"";1);MID(B2;8;1);"";1);MID(B2;7;1);"";1);MID(B2;6;1);"";1);MID(B2;5;1);"";1);MID(B2;4;1);"";1);MID(B2;3;1);"";1);MID(B2;2;1);"";1);MID(B2;1;1);"";1)
```

Here is an [Examlpe](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SlQziVzXvdnHPer_ni0QSm44TZyViyYJ1ddiBoO7F30/edit?usp=sharing).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dynamic formula you could try:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=INDEX(TEXTJOIN("",1,FILTER(MID(A2,SEQUENCE(LEN(A2)),1),NOT(MATCH(MID(A2,SEQUENCE(LEN(A2)),1),MID(A2,SEQUENCE(LEN(A2)),1),0)=SEQUENCE(LEN(A2))*MMULT(--(MID(A2,SEQUENCE(LEN(A2)),1)=MID(B2,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(B2)),1)),SEQUENCE(LEN(B2),1,1,0))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I'm going with. It was posted by Ed(Ohio) [here](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/162969761?hl=en&msgid=162987148).

```
  =CONCATENATE(filter(split(regexreplace(A2,"",","),","),
  (countifs(split(regexreplace(A2,"",","),","),
            split(regexreplace(A2,"",","),","),
            SEQUENCE(1, len(A2)), "<=" & SEQUENCE(1, len(A2)))<>1)+
            (ifna(match(split(regexreplace(A2,"",","),","),
                        split(regexreplace(B2,"",","),","),0))=0)))
```

Thanks everyone for your help.